# HTML Unit Button click

Tags: java, url, button, htmlunit

still working on the Wire-Login. Still got some problems clicking the Login button. https://app.wire.com/auth/#login

Used:

> webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
>           System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log","org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

Button looks like this :

> input id="wire-password-login" class="button button-white btn-action
>   btn-sign-in-email" type="submit" data-bind="enable:
>   can_login_password, l10n_input: z.string.auth_account_sign_in"
>   data-uie-name="do-sign-in" value="Login"

I tried many solutions, here are some:

```
HtmlSubmitInput Button = page1.getHtmlElementById("wire-password-login");
HtmlPage page2 = Button.click();
```

or

```
HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Login").click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
System.out.println(page2.getUrl());
```

...

```
HtmlSubmitInput Login = page1.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id='wire-password-login']");
HtmlPage page2 = Login.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
System.out.println(page2.getUrl());
```

**There are no errors but page2 is always the same url like page1.**

---

If it helps here is my Input-Username code:

```
HtmlTextInput usernameInput = page1.getHtmlElementById("wire-login-username");
usernameInput.setValueAttribute("Answer42@Kappa.de");
System.out.println(usernameInput.getValueAttribute());
```

same for password with HtmlPasswordInput. Pretty sure both work fine.

---

--> So i got no idear why my ButtonClicks dont work? Any hints?

Url from Page 2 should be something like : https://app.wire.com/auth/#history or app.wire.com

Thanks.